# Given an array of unique numbers, list the combination of numbers which sum equals to given integer

Tags: javascript, lodash

Input

```
 Array =[4,2,8,11,14,6,1]
     Expectedtotal=20
```

Output

```
[2,4,6,8], [11,8,1],[6,11,1,2],[2,14,4],[14,6]
```

code:

```js
const arr = [4, 2, 8, 11, 14, 6, 1];
const target = 20;
res = _.filter(arr, v => _.filter(arr, v1 => _.filter(arr, v2 => _.filter(arr, v3 => v + v1 + v2 + v3 === target))); console.log(res);
```

I am the beginner of javascript and lodash. I tried this code by own..please help me to write good code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't know if you are quizzing or asking how to get the expected output. Please edit/update your post with the relevant source code **[Your attempt(s)]** Thank you.

Comment: You're using Stack Overflow wrong. We dont do your homework for you. Your problem is thta you dont know how to do it from a logical point of view, not a practical one. Show your work and tell us errors you get.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a temporary array and the index and iterate the next index by either taking the actual value or not.

```js
function subsetSum(array, sum) {

    function iter(index, temp, s) {
        if (s === sum) return result.push(temp.slice());              // exit sum found
        if (index >= array.length) return;                            // exit index over
        iter(index + 1, temp.concat(array[index]), s + array[index]); // take value
        iter(index + 1, temp, s);                                     // omit value
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(0, [], 0);
    return result;
}

console.log(subsetSum([4, 2, 8, 11, 14, 6, 1], 20).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```